# Greatest value of f

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

If $f'(x)=6-x$ then which of the following has the greatest value?

1. $f(2.01)-f(2)$
2. $f(3.01)-f(3)$
3. $f(4.01)-f(4)$
4. $f(5.01)-f(5)$
5. $f(6.01)-f(6)$

I know the answer is $f(2.01)-f(2)$ but how to prove?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:Use the

$$f'(x)\approx \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ with $h=0.01$.